# Glusterfs dont mirror supposed mirrored folder

Tags: linux, high-availability, glusterfs, mirroring

**Gluster dont replicate mirrored content**:

xfce4-terminal -T LocalTerm
exit

At LocalTerm:

```
PS1='[\u@\h]-[\D{%T}]-[\W] => '  

lxc profile copy default default-bkp  
lxc profile set default raw.lxc lxc.apparmor.profile=unconfined  

clear   
lxc stop ubt1804X64C001  
lxc stop ubt1804X64C002  

lxc delete ubt1804X64C001  
lxc delete ubt1804X64C002  

lxc launch ubuntu:18.04 ubt1804X64C001  
lxc launch ubuntu:18.04 ubt1804X64C002  

clear  
sleep 10  

lxc list --format csv  

lxc config get ubt1804X64C001 security.privileged  
lxc config set ubt1804X64C001 security.privileged true  
lxc config get ubt1804X64C002 security.privileged  
lxc config set ubt1804X64C002 security.privileged true  
lxc restart ubt1804X64C001  
lxc restart ubt1804X64C002    

xfce4-terminal -T ubt1804X64C001Term -e "bash -c 'lxc exec ubt1804X64C001 -- /bin/bash; exec bash; exit 0;'"   
xfce4-terminal -T ubt1804X64C002Term -e "bash -c 'lxc exec ubt1804X64C002 -- /bin/bash; exec bash; exit 0;'"
```

At ubt1804X64C001Term and ubt1804X64C002Term:

```
PS1='[\u@\h]-[\D{%T}]-[\W] => '  
echo '' >> /etc/hosts  
apt-get update   

apt-get upgrade  
apt-get dist-upgrade  
apt-get autoremove  
apt-get install netcat net-tools  
lsb_release -a  
    No LSB modules are available.  
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
    Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS  
    Release:    18.04  
    Codename:   bionic  
uname -a  
    Linux ubt1804X64C001 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux   
cat /etc/fstab  
    LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults    0 0  
apt-get install attr fuse libaio1 liburcu-dev libxml2 python2.7 python-pip rpcbind   
echo '' > ~/testAttr  
setfattr -n user.name -v "UserNameValue" ~/testAttr  
setfattr -n trusted.glusterfs.test -v "working" ~/testAttr  
getfattr -d -m - ~/testAttr  
    trusted.glusterfs.test="working"  
    user.name="UserNameValue"  
add-apt-repository ppa:gluster/glusterfs-4.1  
apt-get update  
    OK   
apt-get install glusterfs-server glusterfs-client open-iscsi watchdog 
glusterfs --version | grep 'glusterfs '  
    glusterfs 4.1.5    
mkdir -p /root/tomirrorwith/glusterfs  
cd /root/tomirrorwith/glusterfs   
ls
```

At ubt1804X64C002Term:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet '  
    20.30.40.50  
echo '10.20.30.40 ubt1804X64C001' >> /etc/hosts   
cat /etc/hostname  
ping ubt1804X64C001  
iptables -I INPUT -p all -s ubt1804X64C001 -j ACCEPT
```

At ubt1804X64C001Term:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet '  
    10.20.30.40  
echo '20.30.40.50 ubt1804X64C002' >> /etc/hosts  
cat /etc/hostname  
ping ubt1804X64C002  
iptables -I INPUT -p all -s ubt1804X64C002 -j ACCEPT  

gluster peer probe ubt1804X64C002  
    peer probe: success  
gluster peer status   
    Number of Peers: 1  
    Hostname: ubt1804X64C002      
    Port: 24007  
    State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)  

gluster volume create gv0 replica 2 ubt1804X64C001:/root/tomirrorwith/glusterfs ubt1804X64C002:/root/tomirrorwith/glusterfs force  
    volume create: gv0: success: please start the volume to access data  
gluster volume start gv0  
    volume start: gv0: success 
echo 'TestValue' > TestFile
```

At ubt1804X64C002Term:

```
cd /root/tomirrorwith/glusterfs   
ls
# There is no TestFile created here on mirrored machine
```

The same issue here: https://github.com/gluster/glusterfs/issues/527